# '!!' versus just checking for "truthy" or "falsy" existence

Tags: javascript, boolean

Re: the `!!` in JavaScript, from my understanding, this will cast an object to a boolean. According to an answer in another SO thread, it "coerces oObject to boolean. If it was falsey (e.g. 0, null, undefined, etc.), it will be false, otherwise, true."

My question therefore is, is this `!!` any more robust than simply checking for falsy or truthy existence? For instance, I could do something like this:

```
return !!(this.services[0] && this.services[0].service);
```

Or I could do this:

```
if (this.services[0] && this.services[0].service) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Are these functionality equivalent?

Comment: If you add an `else { return false; }`, they’re equivalent, yes. You wouldn’t use `!!` in an `if`’s condition, but it matters if you want a consistent return type, for example, like here.

Comment: Are you asking if it's *ever* useful, or about your case specifically?

Comment: @shmosel, I was asking if they're functionality equivalent. And it sounds like, other than one being more terse than the other, they are, in terms of my examples above.

Comment: You're comparing apples to oranges. `!!` isn't an alternative way to *check* a value, it's meant to *change* a value from one type to another. So, again, are you asking about your particular example, or about the general use case?

Comment: There do not exist any values of `a` and `b` such that `if(a&&b){return true}else{return false}` will ever produce a different value `return !!(a&&b)`.

Comment: @shmosel, I don't think you're understanding what I'm asking here. See answers below.

Comment: If I understood what you're asking, I wouldn't have asked you to clarify. :) In your example, the answer is yes, they're functionally equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&&` returns the first falsy value, so `!!(val1 && val2)` may be better if you truly need the consistency of a boolean.

An example would be if you are watching for changes to an expression (like in AngularJS):

```
$scope.$watch(() => val1 && val2, (newVal, oldVal) => { 
    //... 
});
```

If `val1` starts out `undefined`, then `val1 && val2` would evaluate to `undefined`. If `val1` later becomes `false`, then `val1 && val2` would evaluate to `false`. So your watcher would execute again when you may not want it to! So it may be better to watch `!!(val1 && val2)`.

Comment: Excellent distinction. I can see how, in my use case then, the !! is more robust.

Comment: This has actually happened to me. I had an API which was optimized so that it left out `null` and `false` properties when serializing `C#` objects to `JSON`. Thus the properties were `undefined` when they got to the browser. Later when I set one of those `undefined` properties to `false` in JavaScript, my watcher executed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are functionally equivalent. `if` uses exactly the same concept of thruthiness as the `!` operator. However, one statement is concise and the other is useless boilerplate.